# Escolher um diretório para salvar a última versão

Tags: visual-studio

Acabei de instalar o Visual Studio, e preciso fazer o Get latest Version, mas como eu acabei de instalar o TFS aparece uma janela para escolher o Local Folder e eu não sei qual escolher.
Preciso de ajuda, não quero salvar as versões em um pasta errada.

Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei qual pasta escolher:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Crie uma pasta em sua maquina onde você deseja salvar os fontes, C:\FONTES. por exemplo e aponte para ela.

Comment: Reginaldo, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Jasminy,

Não existe bem uma pasta certa ou errada para isso. O ideal é que você inclua em um diretório que seja padrão para você, no meu caso, quando utilizo repositórios TFVC como é o caso do seu exemplo, eu utilizo C:\Projetos.

Um bom ponto que acredito que você deva se atentar, é mapear a pasta do projeto inteira, e não só a pasta de views como é o caso do seu print, pois você pode precisar dos demais arquivos, e vai ser um pouco mais trabalhoso para você refazer todo o mapeamento apenas para conseguir baixar o restante do projeto em um momento posterior. Levando em conta seu print, eu sugiro que você realize o mapeamento apartir de "demandas".